# How to tell which version of Three.js is loaded in browser?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can you tell which version of the Three.js library the browser is currently using?

I have tried all of these in the console:

```
THREE.version 
THREE.version() 
THREE.v
THREE.v()
```

But they are all undefined.

Answer (score 23):

Type `THREE.REVISION` in the console.

Three.js uses the word *revision* rather than *version*. You will often see discussion on SO referring to *r84* as short hand for "revision 84".

BTW, Three.js automatically logs this number to the console whenever an instance of `THREE.WebGLRenderer` is initialised. Look near the top of the console for something like:

```
  THREE.WebGLRenderer 84        three.min.js:154
>
```

Comment: console.log(THREE.REVISION);